# Javascript get dynamically set data-* attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have multiple elements with the class `game_join_a`, with their respective `data-tbl` attributes set dynamically from a database. I want to retrieve those atrributes to further use them in my code.

The code I'm using below returns tells me that `a[i]` is undefined.

```
a = document.getElementsByClassName("game_join_a");
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    a[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(a[i].getAttribute("data-tbl"));
    });
}
```

Comment: Try `console.log(this.getAttribute("data-tbl"));`

Comment: Okay, that worked. But why did the `addEventListener` work without using `this`?

Comment: Because when the event listener is bound it is inside the for loop so a[i] is defined. When the click event is triggered a[i] is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = document.getElementsByClassName("game_join_a");
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    a[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(this.getAttribute("data-tbl"));
    });
}
```

`this` refers to the element that the click event is binded to. If you're dynamically adding the elements rather than just the `data-` attributes, you could also try this:

```
var a = document.getElementById('game_join_container'); // just something that contains all the elements that will be dynamically added

a.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    // check to see if original element clicked is a "game_join_a" element first
    if(event.target.classList.contains('game_join_a')) {
        console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-tbl'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that  `classList` property is not supported by IE9 and lower... http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("game_join_a");
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-tbl"));
    }, false);
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/xuzufo/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: Nothing wrong with that answer it's just a different way of doing it